# Creating an SSH tunnel from a linux VPS to a web server database

Tags: ssh, mysql, ssh-tunneling

I'm creating a server application that clients will connect to. The server application is running on an Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 VPS. The server needs to be able to connect to a MySQL database hosted on a web server. This should be easy to do normally, but my web host, Namecheap, [requires an SSH tunnel instead of directly connecting to a database externally](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1249/89/how-to-remotely-connect-to-mysql-database-located-on-our-shared-server).

If the server was running on Windows, I'm able to set up a simple tunnel with PuTTY to the webserver, but I am unsure on how to do this on a linux system.

It's hard to find information on this, because whatever I look up assumes I'm trying to create a tunnel from a personal Windows computer to a Linux VPS. How can I create a tunnel to a database as described in [this](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/1249/89/how-to-remotely-connect-to-mysql-database-located-on-our-shared-server) link on Ubuntu Server rather than Windows, which has GUI tools like PuTTY that make it easier? (I'm very new to the Linux world)

The tunnel I created in PuTTY (When testing on Windows) looks like: `L3306   127.0.0.1:3306`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized the solution was much simpler than I expected, simply create an SSH tunnel like so:

```
ssh -f -p port username@ip -L 3306:ip:3306 -N
```

Where `port` is the port of the web server, and `ip` is the IP address of it.

I'm working on using  [AutoSSH](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) to keep a persistent connection.

Comment: This will likely work but seems like a giant kludge. You might want to look at setting up an actual VPN.